# Problema no primeiro clock na leitura de uma ROM

Tags: vhdl

Olá, estou tentando fazer uma ROM em VHDL onde uma certa quantidade de bytes é armazenada e, ao receber um pulso de clock, um dos valores é lido e enviado para a saída enquanto que o contador da memória é incrementado em +1. O problema que  verifiquei é que no primeiro evento de clock não está ocorrendo a leitura da memória.

**Código da entidade**

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity memoria is
    Port ( clock, reset :in STD_LOGIC;
              valor : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
           vazia : out  STD_LOGIC);
end memoria;

architecture Behavioral of memoria is

    type ROM is array (0 to 4) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0); --Read only memory

    constant mem : ROM := (b"00000000", b"00000001", b"00000010", b"00000011", b"11111111"); --"11111111" is the stop value
    signal mem_value : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);

begin
    process(clock, reset)
        variable counter : integer := 0;
    begin

        if reset = '1' then
            valor <= "11111111";
            vazia <= '1';

        elsif clock'event and clock = '1' then
            mem_value <= mem(counter);  --gets the current memory value

            if mem_value = "11111111" then --checks if the value read is the stop one
                vazia <= '1';
            else
                vazia <= '0';
            end if;

            valor <= mem_value;             --sends the memory value read to the output
            if counter < 4 then
                counter := counter + 1; --increases counter by one
            end if;
        else
            valor <= "11111111";
            vazia <= '0';
        end if;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

**Test Bench**

```
ENTITY memoria_tb IS
END memoria_tb;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF memoria_tb IS 

   --Inputs
   signal clock : std_logic;-- := '0';
    signal reset : std_logic := '0';

    --Outputs
   signal valor : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
   signal vazia : std_logic;

   -- Clock period definitions
   constant clock_period : time := 10 ns;

BEGIN

    -- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
   uut: entity work.memoria PORT MAP (
          clock => clock,
             reset => reset,
          valor => valor,
          vazia => vazia
        );

   -- Clock process definitions
   clock_process :process
   begin
        clock <= '0';
        wait for clock_period/2;
        clock <= '1';
        wait for clock_period/2;
   end process;  
END;
```

[image: Erro no primeiro pulso de clock]

Gostaria de saber como fazer com que o primeiro valor da memória já seja lido no primeiro pulso de clock. Desde já agradeço por qualquer ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

O problema era que os outputs devem ser setados após o process.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity memoria is
    Port ( clock, reset :in STD_LOGIC;
              valor : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
           vazia : out  STD_LOGIC);
end memoria;

architecture Behavioral of memoria is

    type ROM is array (0 to 4) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0); --Read only memory

    constant mem : ROM := (b"00000000", b"00000001", b"00000010", b"00000011", b"11111111"); --"11111111" is the stop value
    signal mem_value : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
    signal empty : STD_LOGIC;

begin
    process(clock, reset)
        variable counter : integer := 0;
    begin

        if reset = '1' then
            mem_value <= "11111111";
            empty <= '1';

        elsif clock'event and clock = '1' then
            mem_value <= mem(counter);  --gets the current memory value

            if mem_value = "11111111" then --checks if the value read is the stop one
                empty <= '1';
            else
                empty <= '0';
            end if;


            if counter < 4 then
                counter := counter + 1; --increases counter by one
            end if;
        else
            mem_value <= "11111111";
            empty <= '0';
        end if;
    end process;

    valor <= mem_value;             --sends the memory value read to the output
    vazia <= empty;
end Behavioral;
```